# boost::asio::high_resolution_timer usage example?

Tags: c++, boost, timer, boost-asio

I am trying to use boost's high resolution timer and getting compilation error. Please find the snippet below,

```
boost::asio::io_service             _svc;
boost::asio::high_resolution_timer  _timer(_svc, boost::chrono::seconds(1));
```

**Error:**

> error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer::basic_waitable_timer(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::chrono::seconds)’

Comment: use boost::posix_time::seconds(1) instead of boost::chrono::seconds(1).

Comment: tried & i'm getting this,error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock>::basic_waitable_timer(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::posix_time::seconds)’

Comment: @Jonathan I upvoted that, but we misremembered (that's for deadline_timer I think)

Answer (score 1):

The high resolution timer apparently uses C++11's chrono library under the hood if available: `boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp` line 48

```
#elif defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_CHRONO)
typedef basic_waitable_timer<
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
  high_resolution_timer;
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4061443a0d0d0a9f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service             _svc;
    boost::asio::high_resolution_timer  _timer(_svc);

    _timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
```